# Docker image should display a message everytime someone runs it

Tags: docker, docker-image

How to build a docker image such that when someone runs a container based on my image a custom message is displayed in the container?

```
docker run <my-image>
> "This is <name>'s image"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the own docker image or use other's docker image which has configuration or code written that way

for example if you will run this

```
sudo docker run -p 80 -e MSG='This message will be displayed on the web page' --rm wouterm/helloworld
```

it will print the message as you wanted, if you want to make your own docker image you can also create it.

here is reference code and files : https://github.com/Wouter-M/docker-hello-world

Comment: can you provide the reference files for tutum/hello-world as these are not available now in the reference link which you have provided above, I want to create an image of my own which prints a message everytime it is run

Comment: files already available at github shared link in answer.